# Linear dependence of $k$ nonzero vectors implies that atleast one of them can be written as unique linear combination of first v_{k-1} vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

**Question**: Prove that, If $v_1,...,v_n$ are linearly dependent nonzero vectors then atleast one vector $v_k$ is unique linear combination of $v_1,...,v_{k-1}$

**How to establish uniqueness?**

**My attempt**: let suppose that $v_k=a_1v_1+...+a_{k-1}v_{k-1}$ and $v_k=b_1v_1+...+b_{k-1}v_{k-1}$ where,
$\{a_1,...,a_{k-1}\}≠\{b_1,...,b_{k-1}\}$ then we have,
$a_1v_1+...+a_{k-1}v_{k-1} =b_1v_1+...+b_{k-1}v_{k-1}$

$\implies (a_1-b_1) v_1+...+(a_{k-1}-b_{k-1})v_{k-1}=0$

**TO prove uniqueness  we must show that, each of the scalars**  $a_1-b_1=0,..., a_{k-1}-b_{k-1}=0$

but how? Please help..

Comment: I think the statement doesn't hold. For instance the vectors $(1,1,1), (2,2,2)$ and $(3,3,3)$ are linearly dependent and nonzero, however any one of them can be written as a linear combination of the other two in many different ways (ie. not uniquely).

Comment: @ElliotHerrington thank you so much sir. $(3,3,3)=1(1,1,1)+1(2,2,2)$ and also $(3,3,3)= (1/2)(1,1,1)+(5/4)(2,2,2)$ :-) It is true false exercise. I stuck on it from two hours because answer key say statement is true.

Comment: @ElliotHerrington: Denoting the vectors as $v_1,v_2,v_3$ in the order, note that $v_2=2v_1$ so $k=2$ is the $k$ that exists as per the statement of the theorem and $v_2=2v_1$ is the unique representation of $v_2$ as linear combination of $v_1$.

Comment: @Koro Yes you are right. I was commenting on OP's original question, which has since been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing $k$ appropriately, the uniqueness is ensured.

Choosing the symbols as in OP, let $k>1$ be the smallest positive integer such that $v_k\in \rm span(v_1,v_2,...,v_{k-1}).$

If no such $k$ exists, then note that $v_i$'s are linearly independent. So there exists one such $k$.

That is, $v_k\in \rm span(v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_{k-1})\implies v_k=c_1v_1+\cdots+c_{k-1}v_{k-1}$ for some scalars $c_i$.

Suppose there exist scalars $c_i'$ such that $\rm v_k=c_1'v_1+\cdots+c_{k-1}'v_{k-1}$.

It follows that $\rm (c_1-c_1')v_1+(c_2-c_2')v_2+\cdots+(c_{k-1}-c_{k-1}')v_{k-1}=0$

If $\rm c_j\ne c_j'$ for some  $j\in \{1,2,..., k-1\}$ then $\rm v_j\in span(v_1,v_2,...,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},...,v_{k-1})$, which contradicts the way $k$ was chosen. So $c_i=c_i'$ for every $i$ establishing the uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.... specially for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think your very first $v_k$ should be $v_n$.  (Doesn't have to be $n$ of course, but something different from $k$.)

Assuming this, if not all the scalars in your last equation were zero, then one of the vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{k-1}$ would be a linear combination of the previous ones.  This would contradict your assumption that $v_k$ is the **first** such vector.

Comment: Sir, according to 'Elliot Herrington hint' uniqueness part does not holds! $(3,3,3)=1(1,1,1)+1(2,2,2)$ and also $(3,3,3)= (1/2)(1,1,1)+(5/4)(2,2,2)$ Is this conclusion is incorrect?

Comment: PLEASE READ the first sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think uniqueness is guaranteed unless you can prove that the rank of the set of $k$ vectors is $k-1$, otherwise you can imagine if you have $k$ vectors $v, 2v, 3v, \dots, kv$, then they are linearly dependent, but there are certainly many ways to represent any of these vectors as a linear combination of the others.